# Uploaded video status via Facebook PHP Business SDK for advertisements

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to create a ad via the Facebook Business SDK. Everything works well until I'm trying to create a AdCreativeVideoData. Code:

```
 protected function createAdVideoCreative($thumbnail_url, $video_id, $name){
    $video_data = new AdCreativeVideoData();
    $video_data->setData(array(
        AdCreativeVideoDataFields::IMAGE_URL => $thumbnail_url,
        AdCreativeVideoDataFields::VIDEO_ID => $video_id,
        AdCreativeVideoDataFields::CALL_TO_ACTION => array(
            'type' => AdCreativeCallToActionTypeValues::LIKE_PAGE,
            'value' => array(
                'page' => FbAds::PAGE_ID,
            ),
        ),
    ));

    $object_story_spec = new AdCreativeObjectStorySpec();
    $object_story_spec->setData(array(
        AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => FbAds::PAGE_ID,
        AdCreativeObjectStorySpecFields::VIDEO_DATA => $video_data,
    ));

    $creative = new AdCreative(null, FbAds::AD_ACCOUNT_ID);

    $creative->setData(array(
        AdCreativeFields::NAME => $name,
        AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
    ));

    try {
        $creative->create();

        return $creative;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print("Create Ad Video Creative Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . " (" . $e->getCode() . ")");

        exit;
    }
}
```

The above method is called when the selected video is uploaded to Facebook via the following method:

```
   protected function createAdVideo($video_path){
    $video = new Advideo(null, FbAds::AD_ACCOUNT_ID);

    $video->{AdVideoFields::SOURCE} = $video_path;

    try {
        $video->create();

        return $video->{AdVideoFields::ID};
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print("Create Ad Video Exception: " . $e->getMessage() . " (" . $e->getCode() . ")");

        exit;
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to create the AdCreativeVideoData, the following error is thrown:

```
[message] => Invalid parameter
[type] => OAuthException
[code] => 100
[error_subcode] => 1885252
[is_transient] => 
[error_user_title] => Video not ready for use in an ad
[error_user_msg] => The video is still being processed. Please wait for the video to finish processing before using it in an ad.
[fbtrace_id] => AwW0d9+Piz1
```

As you can see, the video is not yet processed. My question is: how can I check the status of the video? Is there a endpoint available somewhere which I can ping to check the status? The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/advideo/) states that I can check the status, but the AdVideo object in the createAdVideo() method doesn't have a status field:

[image: AdVideo fields]

I'm at a loss here so I hope someone can shed a light on this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

*AdVideo* does not have a `status` field since then, but *Video* does: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video

Internally it's the same `id`, so you can request `https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/{video-id}?fields=id,status` which will return the status of the uploaded *(Ad)Video*.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume it is because the video is not uploaded at all.
Instead of using "source" try using "file_url". You may also want to add a parameter "title" so it will not be named untitled video- but it is not required.

And try using the SDK smarter like so:

```
$myVideoUpload = (new AdAccount("act_123456676"))-
>createAdVideo(
array() //fields
array( //params
"file_url"=>"http://whatever.com",
"title"=>"my title"
)
);
```

if this works, it'll return a json_encodes string with id=video_id.

If you want to be able to retrieve errors- if any- and a general method for all api calls, do use the graph api as such:

```
$fb = new Facebook(array(
"app_id"=>"blalaa",
"app_secret"=>"blaaaaa",
"default_graph_version"=>"v9.0"
));
$url = "/act_123456789/advideos";
$access_token = "my token";
$params = 
array("file_url"=>"https://whatever.com","title"=>"some video");
try{
 $response = $fb->post(
  $url,
  $params,
  $access_token
 )
 $response = $response->getGraphNode();
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
  return "graph error:: " . $e->getMessage();
} catch(FacebookSDKException$e) {
  return "sdk error:: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The last one can be applied to everything given that you have an access_token that has access to the specific edge that you are requesting thus only he URL needs to be changed accordingly along with the parameters.

Note:
While using the graph-api: Use POST if you want to change or create something, and GET if you only want to read.